# How to pass reference (non-serializable) from one Activity to another?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Say I have an reference to an object, how should I go about passing this from one Activity to another?

I don't want to have to query the Application Object / singletons / static variables.

Is this still possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can declare a static variable in another activity, or some Global Variable in Application class, then access it to any activity, like you want to parse some Object of Type NewType, to Class NewActivity, from OldActivity. Do as Following:

Declare an Object of Static NewType in NewActivity.java.

```
public static NewObject newObject=null;
```

do Following, when you invoke NewActivity.

```
NewActivity.newObject=item;
Intent intent=new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi, I would rather not have the Activity reaching out to a static variable / the application object.

Comment: If you want to pass some object through intent then you can use Bundle, but to put some value in bundle, it should be a parcelable object, and if it does not then you have to device some other way, to pass object, and as Android ActivityManager, itself invoke constructor of Activity you, cant pass parameter in constructor. I dont think there is any other way.

Comment: This was not the answer I was looking for, but it seems like it is because of the framework not supporting the behavior I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Is not a solution when you need to use onSaveInstanceState is impossible to replicate this solution when you need to use Bundle, especially when the application is paused, rotated, you block your phone, you switch applications, etc, this solution terminates in an exception when the function onCreate not find the static variable.

Comment: Doesn't that potentially leak your context out of the application making it memory-leak prone? Ie. if the object has a context reference to an activity, it will never be GC'ed unless you null it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one of the following ways :

- Make the object Static. (easiest but not always efficient)
- Serialize -> send -> receive -> deserialize . You can use something like [JSON decoding and encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785082/json-deserializing-with-json-parsing-in-android-application) too, if your class is not serializable.  (Involves a lot of over-head, you dont want to use this, unless you have a good reason)
- Parcelable( Most efficient, Fastest)

Here's an eg from the docs : you can wrap your object with a `parcelable`, attach it to an intent, and 'un-wrap' it in the recieving activity.

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the Solution:

You can make a singleton class to carry the information you want

for example:

```
StorageManager.getInstance().saveSomething(Object obj);
```

then retrieve back with respective getter method

Make sure you take care of the synchronization issues;)