# pass data from one activity to another in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I wanted to pass a `Class Object` from one activity to another in `Xamarin.Android` app.
I can pass the simple strings using `Intent.PutExtra` method.

Does anybody know about it. anyhelp is appreciated :)

Comment: You can use a component on the Xamarin store called Simple storage, will essentially do the hard work for you. https://components.xamarin.com/view/simple-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept is the same as with a standard (non-Xamarin) application.

You can use [`Intent#putExtra(String, Parcelable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable)) to pass any object that implements the [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface as an extra.

The `Parcelable` interface is a little bit complex, so be sure to read the documentation to ensure that your class conforms to the requirements. You may also want to check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable) for more information on creating a `Parcelable` class.

You cannot pass an object reference via an `Intent`. This is because Activities are designed to work completely independently of each other. Users can throw your Activity in the background while performing other tasks, so it is entirely possible (and very likely) that your Activity's variables will be garbage collected. When the user later comes back to your Activity, it should be able to recreate its state.

If you really need to pass a reference to an object directly, you can do so by making that object a static variable. While this is a quick and dirty way to solve the problem of getting data from one Activity to another, it does not solve the problem of the variable potentially being garbage collected at some point, and is generally a poor design choice.

Comment: Will Object be passed as a reference ?

Comment: No. It will be bundled into a `Parcel`, and then restored from that `Parcel` when you retrieve it.

Comment: How can I achieve this reference passing of object to another activity ?

Comment: I recommend you don't. Activities are designed to run completely independently of each other. It is possible (and very likely) that the user will throw your Activity in the background while doing some other task, and will come back to it later. At that point, the object you were trying to maintain might have been garbage collected. If you REALLY need to, you could store the object statically and retrieve it in the new Activity.

Comment: I am pretty new to android, you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733361/how-to-pass-reference-non-serializable-from-one-activity-to-another this way.

Comment: Yes, that would be an example of passing a static variable. Be aware that this is still prone to your variable being garbage collected, so you need to have a backup plan in your second Activity if your static variable is null.

Comment: Update you ans with this info I mark that right. but for now +1

Comment: @Tanis.7x why all examples of Parcelable implementation are Java? The idea of using Xamarin is to have all in C#, isn't it?

Comment: @Riga Because [Xamarin's documentation for Parcelable](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.Parcelable/) is just a copy-paste of Google's documentation, and Google's is typically better with regards to what is happening with the API. [Here's a blog post with a good Xamarin example](http://dan.clarke.name/2012/09/implementing-iparcelable-in-mono-for-android/).

Comment: @Tanis.7x the link what you added is what I expected to find in Xamarin website. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Just adding in case someone else comes across this. The nice thing about Xamarin/.NET is how easy it is to use JSON. You can Serialize your data to a string and pass that through the Extras.

`JSON.NET` is a nice library (that you can find on the Xamarin component store) for this and there is also some built in JSON classes in .NET. An example using JSON.NET would be like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(SecondActivity));
i.PutExtra("key", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject));
StartActivity(i);
```

And in the other `Activity` you can deserialize it.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OBJ_TYPE>(Intent.GetStringExtra("key"));
```

This is better than using a static reference in my opinion.

Comment: thanks, it really didn't come to my mind :) but I need to pass object by reference :)