# Canceling an Firebase Storage UploadTask

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

My use case is simple. Upload multiple images in the background and show the progress in a notification. Now I want to cancel this task when the user presses the cancel button in the notification. As the upload task cannot be serialized then how am I supposed to cancel that particular upload task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Upload multiple images in the background and show the progress in a notification.

For those operations, I assume you are using a line of code similar to this:

```
UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(filePath);
```

> Now I want to cancel this task when the user presses the cancel button in the notification.

As seen the above line of code, the [putFile(Uri uri)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#putFile(android.net.Uri)) method that is called on a [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) object, returns an object of type [UploadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask). This class is a subclass of [StorageTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTask), which in terms is a subclass of [ControllableTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/ControllableTask), which is also a subclass of [CancellableTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/CancellableTask).

Because of the inheritance relationship between these classes, you can simply call CancellableTask's [cancel()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/CancellableTask#cancel()) method:

> Attempts to cancel the task.

In order to cancel the Task. In code should look like this:

```
uploadTask.cancel();
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. But that is what i am concerned about. How will i get the instance of this particular uploadTask that I need to cancel. I need to pass it via intent. Somewhat like this: `intent.putExtra("task", (Parcelable) uploadTask);`. But uploadTask is **not Parcelable** nor Serializable. @Alex_Mamo

Comment: As you already mentioned, you cannot pass an instance of UploadTask via Intent, since it's not Parcelable nor Serializable. What you can do, is to make it [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733361/how-to-pass-reference-non-serializable-from-one-activity-to-another), or convert that object to a [Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012615/how-to-pass-non-parcelable-objects-to-from-activity-to-another-activity) one, right?